# Django formset and form ValidationError

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

I am facing validation error when I am trying to save form and formset at the same time.
ValidationError

> at /event-admin-2/ [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been
>   tampered with']

post method:

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    event_times = EventTime.objects.filter(event = self.object).exclude(start_time = None)
    if 'update_event_form' in request.POST:
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, prefix="foo", instance=self.get_object())
        formset = self.second_form_class(request.POST, prefix="foo2", queryset=event_times)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/event-admin-%s' %self.kwargs['event_id']) 
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))
```

Template:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>{%csrf_token%}
                {% crispy formset event_time_formset_helper %}
                <button id='add-time' type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="update_event_form" value="Update" />
            </form>
```

HTML output:

```
<div> <input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="4" /> <input id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1" /> <input id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1" /> <input id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000" /> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set `prefix='foo'` at the place where you instantiate the formset in the post method, but presumably not wherever you do it in the get method.

Comment: I moved prefix declaration to context method, but still the same error

Comment: Needs to be in *both* places.